# Failed to find data source: com.stratio.datasource.mongodb

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I read all different issues from other Stratio packages, but I couldn't solve my problem.

When I try with the:
 "./bin/spark-submit --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.11:0.12.0 "

or

"./bin/spark-submit --jars /home/user/Spark-MongoDB/spark-mongodb_2.11/target/spark-mongodb_2.11-0.12.1-RC1-SNAPSHOT.jar" .

I've been struggling with this for the past two days, what is it Im doing wrong? I'm using spark 2.0.0, Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command I am using on my test machine and it is working fine.

> spark-submit --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.11:0.12.0 --master local[1] Cell.py

I have the same environment i.e. Ubuntu 14.04, scala 2.11 and spark 2.0.0

I am trying to write data to mongodb using my python program and it is working as expected.

Comment: if its a sample python file can u send me the code... Also is this line correct res.write.format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").mode('append').options(host='127.0.0.1:27017', database='panoids', collection='city', idField='_id', splitKey='_id').save()

Comment: Your line seems correct to me. 

Part of the code ( here lines is my rdd and sc is the SparkSession)
recs = sc.createDataFrame(lines, ["date","activecount"])
recs.write.format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").mode("overwrite").options(host='db:27017', database='test', collection='daily_activecounts').save()